# Turning parent-child data frame into a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, parent-child

I have the following data frame:

```
data = [
    {"id": 1, "parent_id": -1, "level": 1, "name": "Company"},
    {"id": 2, "parent_id": 1, "level": 2, "name": "Bakery"},
    {"id": 3, "parent_id": 1, "level": 2, "name": "Frozen"},
    {"id": 4, "parent_id": 2, "level": 3, "name": "Bread"},
    {"id": 5, "parent_id": 2, "level": 3, "name": "Pastry"},
    {"id": 6, "parent_id": 3, "level": 3, "name": "Ice Cream"},
    {"id": 7, "parent_id": 3, "level": 3, "name": "Sorbet"},
]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

that looks like this:

```
   id  parent_id  level       name
0   1         -1      1    Company
1   2          1      2     Bakery
2   3          1      2     Frozen
3   4          2      3      Bread
4   5          2      3     Pastry
5   6          3      3  Ice Cream
6   7          3      3     Sorbet
```

I'm trying to represent the data as a dictionay like this:

```
data = {
    "Company": {
        "Bakery": [
            "Bread",
            "Pastry",
        ],
        "Frozen": [
            "Ice Cream",
            "Sorbet",
        ],
    },
}
```

Heavily struggling with achieving this result, so any help is appreciated! I've tried various for-loops but getting muddled up!

Comment: The logic is not very clear to me. Can you provide further details, please?

Answer (score 2):

This is what I came up with (this code assumes consistency between `parent_id`s and `level`s and that all `parent_id`s exist):

```
# to store the final result
result = {}

# to store references of dictionaries by their ids
by_id = {}

for d in sorted(data, key=lambda d: d['level']):
    new_dict = {}
    if d['parent_id'] == -1:
        result[d['name']] = new_dict
    else:
        by_id[d['parent_id']][d['name']] = new_dict
    by_id[d['id']] = new_dict
```

At this point:

```
>>> result
{'Company': {'Bakery': {'Bread': {}, 'Pastry': {}}, 'Frozen': {'Ice Cream': {}, 'Sorbet': {}}}}
```

Now to convert empty dictionaries to a list of items, we use a recursive function:

```
def transform_dicts_to_lists(r):
    if any(r.values()):
        for k, v in r.items():
            r[k] = transform_dicts_to_lists(v)
        return r
    else:
        return list(r.keys())


result = transform_dicts_to_lists(result)
```

```
>>> result
{'Company': {'Bakery': ['Bread', 'Pastry'], 'Frozen': ['Ice Cream', 'Sorbet']}}
```

You can avoid final processing if you know that the maximum level is always 3.

Comment: This is what I'm after thanks ... very verbose (was hoping there was some pandas magic!

Comment: Pandas is not meant for this kind (table to JSON) of manipulations.